# Отправка документа из формы в телеграмм бота через API

Tags: php, post, telegram-bot, telegram

Вот так работает хорошо

```html
<form action="https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <p><b>ID пользователя:</b>
 <input type="text" name="chat_id" value="*******"></p>

 <p><b>Файл для отправки:</b>
 <input type="file" name="document"></p>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Но так как токен лежит на поверхности, хотелось бы данные получать в php файл и отправлять уже из него. Не могу понять, как мне правильно распарсить поле с файлом и отправить его.

Пробовал все вариации с `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` - не работает, пробовал загружать файл на сервер, и уже отправлять ссылку на него прямую - не работает, ограничение по типу файлов. 
Направьте, пожалуйста...

В данный момент пытаюсь отправить вот так:

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendDocument";
// $_document = "ok.json";
$_document = $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'];
$document = new CURLFile(realpath($_document));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["chatID" => *****]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:multipart/form-data']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($out);
```

Ну и HTML форму на фронте:

```
<form action="raketa_api.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <p><b>Файл для отправки:</b>
    <input type="file" name="document"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000" />

    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

В ответ получаю ошибку `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no document in the request"}`

Comment: В чём заключается проблема? В получении файла на сервере или отправка его в Telegram?

Comment: `Не могу понять, как мне правильно распарсить поле с файлом и отправить его.`

Comment: Не понял эту фразу. Разбейте задачу на части: 1) получение файла и временное сохранение его на сервере; 2) затем отправка. С какой частью возникли затруднения?

Comment: Какую библиотеку/фреймворк для работы с API используете?

Comment: Обновил вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendDocument";
                // $_document = "ok.json";
                $_document = $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'];
            $document = new CURLFile(realpath($_document));
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["chat_id" => "*****", "document" => $document]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type:multipart/form-data"]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            $out = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            print_r($out);
```

Не передавался аргумент с файлом. 
Теперь файл отправляется нормально, но с тестовым именем. Доработать немного код и все будет супер! Всем спасибо!